# Autocomplete field in a form ? []

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, forms

I work with c# MVC3 & razor, Entity Framework and Linq.

I have a form, with two field, the first one **Client ID**  and the second one **Store Name**.
I would like, when the user enter the ID, then my StoreName field fill automatically... The data would come from a database where this two data are stored.

Comment: It would autocomplete from what data? Based on what information? So you have a firstname typed by the user. Where will the lastname come from? A database? What if there are multiple lastnames associated to the given firstname? Also don't forget to mention in your question [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far and what specific difficulties you encountered with the code you have attempted.

Comment: I've updated my question, I hope it will be a bit more clear... I'd like to have tried something, but I really don't see how doing it, where begin or what looking for on the internet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use AJAX. So setup a controller action taking a client id as parameter and that would query your database and return the corresponding store name as JSON result. Then subscribe to the `.blur` event of the text input containing the store id and send an AJAX call to the controller action to fill the second input field.

Yeah, I know, meaningless jibber-jabber, gimme the codez.

Here:

```
public ActionResult GetStoreName(int clientId)
{
    // of course thath's just an example here. I have strictly no idea
    // what database access technology you are using, how your models look like
    // and so on. Obviously you will have to adapt this query to your data model.
    var client = db.Clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == clientId);
    if (client == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return Json(new { storeName = client.Store.Name }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now assuming the following view:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ClientId)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ClientId, new { id = "clientId", data-url = Url.Action("GetStoreName") })
</div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Store.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Store.Name, new { id = "storeName" })
</div>
```

in a separate javascript file you could subscribe to the [`.blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event of the first textbox, and trigger the AJAX request to the controller sending it the client id that was entered by the user. In the success callback you would update the second textfield with the result of the AJAX call:

```
$(function() {
    $('#clientId').blur(function() {
        var clientId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: { clientId: clientId },
            success: function(result) {
                $('#storeName').val(result.storeName);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot, you have given me more than I expected. I'll work on it

Comment: I have an issue with this line `new { id = "clientId", data-url = Url.Action("GetStoreName") } `  on "url-data". It say it does not exist in the actual context. What is it and what is this attribute for ?